# ManyToMany Hibernate in Kotlin

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, quarkus

I am trying to build Many To Many relationship in Kotlin as the following:

```
@Entity
data class Gender(@field:Id var abbr: Char? = null,
                  var description: String = "") : PanacheEntityBase

@Entity
data class Interest(
    var description: String = ""): PanacheEntity()

@Entity
data class User(@field:Id var id: UUID? = null,
                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) var gender: Gender? = null,
                var birthday: Long = 0,
                @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
                @JoinTable(
                    name = "user_interests",
                    joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
                    inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "interest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
                )
                var interests: List<Interest> = listOf()) : PanacheEntityBase
```

and I receive error messages:

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table if exists User cascade" via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists User cascade" via JDBC Statement

Error executing DDL "create table User (id uuid not null, birthday int8 not null, gender_abbr char(1), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table User (id uuid not null, birthday int8 not null, gender_abbr char(1), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
  Position: 22
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I bet "User" is a reserved keyword in SQL and i don't see any backticks or other escape mechanisms in the error.  You could try using another name for the table that isn't a reserved keyword in SQL or try to find the right configuration so that all table and column names are correctly escaped in the generated SQL.

Comment: I have changed to account and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue multiple times, it happens because `user` is a reserved keyword in most SQL dialects.

Easiest solution is to rename it, e.g add application prefix(e.g `sw_user` or `SwUser` in kotlin).

Another possible option can be to use doublequotes, something like

```
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
@Entity
data class User
```

This approach is a bit risky and might not work on all the databases.

There's also a list of all the [reserved sql keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words)